# Kubernetes pod wont start and get CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, kubernetes, networking

When i try to run `kubectl apply -f frontend.yaml` i get the following response from `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl describe pods`

```
// frontend.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: malvacom-frontend
  labels:
    app: malvacom-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: malvacom-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: malvacom-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: malvacom-frontend
          image: docker.io/forsrobin/malvacom_frontend
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /index.html
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 1
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /index.html
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 1
          command: [ "sleep" ]
          args: [ "infinity" ]
```

and then the responses are

```
kubectl get pods
malvacom-frontend-8575c8548b-n959r   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (95s ago)   4m38s
```

```
kubectl describe pods
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  17s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/malvacom-frontend-8575c8548b-n959r to shoot--p1622--malvacom-web-xdmoi2-z1-54776-bpjpw
  Normal   Pulled     15s (x2 over 16s)  kubelet            Container image "docker.io/forsrobin/malvacom_frontend" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    15s (x2 over 16s)  kubelet            Created container malvacom-frontend
  Normal   Started    15s (x2 over 16s)  kubelet            Started container malvacom-frontend
  Warning  BackOff    11s (x4 over 14s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

As I understran the pod starts but because it has no continues task to do kubernetes removes/stops the pod. I can run the image localy without any problem and if i for example use another image `thenetworkchuck/nccoffee:pourover`  it works without any problems. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./package.json /app/
RUN yarn --silent
COPY . /app
RUN yarn build
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly telling Kubernetes to not run its normal server

```yaml
command: [ "sleep" ]
args: [ "infinity" ]
```

but then it should pass an HTTP health check

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /index.html
    port: 80
```

Since `sleep infinity` doesn't run an HTTP server, this probe will never pass, which causes your container to get killed and restarted.

You shouldn't need to do artificial things to "keep the container alive"; delete the `command:` and `args:` override.  (The Dockerfile `CMD` is correct, but you get an identical `CMD` from the base `nginx` image and you don't need to repeat it.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! It still does not work when I delete the `cmd`, `args` and `livenessProbe` checks. Still gets CrashLoopBackOff with the following description from kubectl:

`Back-off restarting failed container`

Any idea on what can cause the problem now?

Comment: Okay, so i found the solution...

Turns out I was building the image on an ARM-based M1 Mac, but then trying to run it on an x86-based cloud instance, which cause all sorts of problems!

To fix it I simply added `--platform=linux/amd64` to all my `FROM`in the Dockerfile, for example,  `FROM nginx:alpine` to `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nginx:alpine`